# Mapping list of objects to list of strings in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a list of User objects, and I want to transform it to a list of names, join it, and present it (not in a table). How do I do it?

```
class User {
  String name;
  String address;
}
```

I have the usersList, and I want to transform it to the list of names, something like this:

```
<body>
    <h1>Names of Users</h1>
    <span>
       <div th:text="${#strings.listJoin(usersList.map( u -> u.name).collect(Collectors.toList()), ',')}"></div>
    </span>
</body>
```

how can I do it in thymeleaf?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions-collection-projection):

```
<body>
    <h1>Names of Users</h1>
    <span>
       <div th:text="${#strings.listJoin(usersList.![name], ',')}" />
    </span>
</body>
```